# How to show that $\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|$ for a bounded linear operator $T$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

I need to show that for a bounded linear operator, $T$, on a Hilbert space:
\begin{align*}
\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|
\end{align*}
All I have so far:

\begin{align*}
\|T^*T\|&=\sup\{|\langle T^*Tf,g \rangle |:\|f\|\le1,\|g\|\le1\}
\\ &= \sup\{|\langle Tf,Tg \rangle|:\|f\|\le1,\|g\|\le1\}
\\ &\le \sup_{\|f\|\le1}\|Tf\|\sup_{\|g\|\le1}\|Tg\|
\end{align*}

Not too sure what to do from here (or even if this is right so far)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|{#1}\right\|}
\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}
$You might find it easier to use an alternative but equivalent definition of the operator norm: if $S \in B(H)$, then
$$
 \norm{S} = \sup_{\norm{x}=1} \norm{Sx}.
$$

Now:

1. On the one hand,
   $$
    \norm{T} = \sup_{\norm{x}=1} \norm{Tx} = \sup_{\norm{x}=1} \sqrt{\ip{Tx,Tx}}.
   $$
   Since $\ip{Tx,Tx} = \ip{x, T^\ast T x} \leq \norm{T^\ast T}\norm{x}$, what can you conclude?
2. On the other hand,
   $$
    \norm{T^\ast T} = \sup_{\norm{x}=1} \norm{T^\ast Tx}.
   $$ 
   Since $\norm{T^\ast T x} \leq \norm{T^\ast} \norm{Tx}$, where $\norm{T^\ast}=\norm{T}$ (why?), what can you conclude?

In terms of wider context, the identity $\norm{T^\ast T} = \norm{T}^2$ is called the *$C^\ast$-identity*, and is the key fact that makes the theory of $C^\ast$-algebras (e.g., $B(H)$ for $H$ a Hilbert space) so much easier (for lack of a better word) than the theory of more general Banach ($\ast$-)algebras, just as the theory of Hilbert spaces is so much easier than the theory of more general Banach spaces.

Comment: Sorry my inner products meant to have absolute values. Why is the $\sup$ taken over $\|x\|=1$?

Comment: Otherwise, one would have to write
$$
 \|S\| = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|S x\|}{\|x\|}.
$$

Comment: Does this mean my steps are wrong?

Comment: Word for word from my book: $T$ bounded operator then         $\\ \|T\|=\sup\{|\langle Tf,g\rangle|:\|f\| \le 1, \|g\| \le 1\}$. I don't understand why this doesn't hold in this case..

Comment: You're right, that definition works, but it's not one I've ever seen used in any of the literature I'm used to, and certainly not one I'd ever think to use, but again, this might be a function of my particular line of work (operator-algebraic noncommutative geometry). The definition involving a supremum over unit vectors has always struck me as the most straightforward one, though I'm sure there are cases where the one you were given would be more useful.

Comment: Ya your definition seems a lot easier to use... however, I probably need to use the definition given in class. I'll readjust my proof accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The first notice that $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$:
From definition of operator norm
\begin{align*}
\|T^*\|&=\sup_{\|y\|=1}\|T^*y\|=\sup_{\|y\|=1}\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(x,T^*y)|=
\sup_{\|y\|=1}\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(Tx,y)|\\
&=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sup_{\|y\|=1}|(Tx,y)|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|=\|T\|
\end{align*}
Therefore $T^*\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$ and $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$.

To conclude, let $x\in H$ with $\|x\|=1$. It follows from
\begin{align}
\|Tx\|^2=(Tx,Tx)=(x,T^*Tx)\leq\|x\|\|T^*Tx\|\leq \|T^*T\|\leq\|T^*\|\|T\|=\|T\|^2
\end{align}
that $\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\langle x, T^*Tx\rangle \leq ||x||~||T^*Tx||$. I think it can be done with cauchy-schwarz but there I only know that $|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq ||x||~||y||$ and in our case we don't have an absolute value.

Comment: @user123234: Indeed, it is an application of Cauchy-Schwartz. notice that $(x,T*Tx)=(Tx,Tx)$ is a nonnegative number thus no need for $|\;|$,

Comment: Perfect thanks!